# SQL Server Update with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, sql-update

```
 insert into tableA (column1) 
 select min(tableC.column1)
 from tableB 
 inner join tableC on (tableC.coumn2 = tableB.column1
 and tableB.column2 = tableA.column2) 
 group by tableA.column2
```

How would I change the above to a update with group by instead of insert with group by based on the criteria `tableB.column2 = tableA.column2` ?

Note that I am using `SQL SERVER 2008.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Update Group by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853403/sql-server-update-group-by)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
  Update A set Column1 = minC    
    from (select Ab.Column2, min(C.Column1) as minC
            from A Ab
            inner join B on Ab.Column2 = B.Column2
            inner join C on C.column2 = B.Column2 --No need to add again the A.col2 = B.col2
            group by Ab.Column2) Grouped where A.Column2 = Grouped.Column2
```

Is this what you want?
This will get for each columnA the `C.Column1` min value, and will update it in `A.Column1` (that's where you were inserting before), based on condition `A.Column2 = Grouped.Column2`.

here is a [SQL-Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/480b4/1)

Comment: another question though: if table A is defined as @A, then how come it returned me an error for the last line of the query:Must declare the scalar variable "@A", and how would i fix this issue?

Comment: That's another question, you should created with an example of the declarated table, and the query you made. Probably is a problem of alias, or the scope of the table

Comment: The problem is right now i cannot write update @A sometable ... where sometable.column2 = Grouped.column2 and everything else stays the same.

Comment: what is "@a sometable"? after update word, you should put a table name, or an alias, not both

Comment: posted another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362141/are-there-any-differences-between-the-results-of-these-2-queries