# Update Table by Join and Group by

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, join, group-by

A Company has many Reviews which has Rating Column itself.

```
CompID  Ratig
12  3
13  3
17  4
22  4
23  5
24  3
28  3,2
```

This is what I need to be set to each company by id. **Now Rating In Company Column is** `NULL`.

I've written something like this:

```
UPDATE Companies c
JOIN Reviews r on c.CompanyID = r.CompanyID
SET c.Rating = AVG(r.rating)
group by r.CompanyID
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Update Group by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853403/sql-server-update-group-by)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do what you want using a simple nested query, in this case probably simpler than a `JOIN`.

```
UPDATE Companies
SET Rating =
  (SELECT AVG(Rating) 
   FROM Ratings
   WHERE Companies.CompanyId = Ratings.CompId)
```

Simple SQLfiddle demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4fc25/2).

EDIT: If you *really* want to use a `JOIN`/`UPDATE FROM`, it'd look something like this;

```
UPDATE c
SET c.Rating = r.Rating
FROM Companies c
JOIN (SELECT AVG(Rating) Rating, CompID FROM Ratings GROUP BY CompId) r
  ON c.CompanyId = r.CompId
```

At least to me, somewhat more complicated to read, and afaik it only works on SQL Server, but [here's the SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/414bb/1) for that too :)

Comment: that works I know. can shortly explain me why is it simpler and how it would be by using group by & join

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE ComisionesxColaboradorxLineaPrescripciones
 SET CANTIDAD_PRODUCTOS_CORE_CUMPLE = CANTIDAD
 FROM @ComisionesxColaboradorxLineaPrescripciones ComisionesxColaboradorxLineaPrescripciones
 INNER JOIN
    (SELECT TAB_L.COD_COLAB AS COD_COLAB,TAB_L.TIPO_COLABORADOR AS TIPO_COLABORADOR, COUNT(TAB_P.COD_SEG) AS CANTIDAD
    FROM @ComisionesxColaboradorxLineaPrescripciones TAB_L
    INNER JOIN @ComisionesxColaboradorxLineaxProductoPrescripciones TAB_P
    ON TAB_L.COD_COLAB=TAB_P.COD_COLAB AND
    TAB_L.TIPO_COLABORADOR=TAB_P.TIPO_COLABORADOR
    GROUP BY TAB_L.COD_COLAB,TAB_L.TIPO_COLABORADOR
    ) AGRUPADO 
        ON ComisionesxColaboradorxLineaPrescripciones.COD_COLAB = AGRUPADO.COD_COLAB AND
        ComisionesxColaboradorxLineaPrescripciones.TIPO_COLABORADOR = AGRUPADO.TIPO_COLABORADOR
```

Comment: omg, this is the ugliest naming of SQL objects I've seen. Anyways, your statement is the same of the second one in accepted solution.