# SQL Server 2012 Update using Select combining 2 rows to get SET value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to calculate a percentage based on two rows next to each other.
The Select statement finds them and calculates correctly but the Update error says:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'

Code:

```
Update L 
Set [TCKR%] = (L.Stock_Close - E.Stock_Close) / L.Stock_Close 
From HistData as L
Inner Join HistData as E on L.RecordID = E.RecordID + 1
Where L.RecordID = L.RecordID
Group by L.RecordID, L.Stock_Close, E.Stock_Close
```

`Order by` does not work either

Comment: You can't use an aggregate in an UPDATE query. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2853556/5948715

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a reason to perform a `GROUP BY` in this case:

```
UPDATE L
SET [TCKR%] = (L.Stock_Close -  E.Stock_Close)/L.Stock_Close 
FROM HistData as L
JOIN HistData AS E on L.RecordID = E.RecordID + 1
```

**Note:** If `Stock_Close` is of type `int` then you have to multiply either the nominator or the denominator by `1.0` so as to avoid integer division.

Comment: the records are not in order unless I order them. This works correctly with group by without it; it updates the wrong rows, Also [TCKR%] is decimal(9,6):  the select works as I said. So it needs to Order the Rows by RecordID somehow.

Comment: Actually your code makes it off my one row its updating the row below
RecordID TICKR%
1   NULL
2         0.0005
3         -0.0003

Comment: Or how can I reorder the Table so RecordID is Ascending by default?

Comment: @R2Builder Can you provide some sample data along with expected result?

Comment: @R2Builder Do you get the correct result if you use on `L.RecordID = E.RecordID - 1` instead of on `L.RecordID = E.RecordID + 1` ?

Comment: Well Record ID 1 is the first record so if you subtract 1 you get a Record ID of 0 and it does not work and then the equation is backwards for the rest. Sample Data, not easily. I have to put the data out on the WEB somewhere which is not do-able for this client.